# al subir un excel con exceljs me trae diferente fecha en angular

Tags: javascript, angular8, excel-2010

estoy teniendo un problema con las fechas de un excel, estoy usando la libreia EXCELJS : La fecha que tengo en un fila es  **D2= 2021-09-15** y la hora en  **E2=22:00**

una vez que subu el excel con el input=file, mapeo las celdas como se en el siguente codigo,

```
const workbook = new Excel.Workbook();
    let dataRowExcel = [];
    const target: DataTransfer = <DataTransfer>(event.target);
    if (target.files.length !== 1) throw new Error('Cannot use multiple files');
    const arryBuffer = await new Response(target.files[0]).arrayBuffer();
    await workbook.xlsx.load(arryBuffer)
    const worksheet = workbook.getWorksheet(1);
    worksheet.eachRow((row) => {
        dataRowExcel.push(row.values);
    });
```

Esto me genera un array con las fechas diferentes
**D2= Tue Sep 14 2021 19:00:00 GMT-0500 (hora estándar de Perú**)  y
**E2= time Sat Dec 30 1899 16:51:24 GMT-0508 (hora estándar de Perú)**

ayuda por favor !!!

Comment: Las fechas y horas en Excel son números. La parte entera de un número es la fecha como tal y la parte decimal la hora. En E2, al tener el valor 22:00, eso en decimal es `0,9166666666` que al pasarlo a fecha se convierte en lo que te da. Dependiendo de lo que quieras, asegúrate que el valor numérico es el correcto. En D2 seguramente tengas un valor numerico próximo a 44453,7916666667 cuando te interesa un entero tipo 44454